# Look up a specific Variant, using the variant's ID?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

When looking up a specific product by ID, you'd do something like this:

```
{% set product = craft.commerce.products.id(productId).first() %}
```

If you instead have a **variant ID** and want to find a specific **variant**, *what is the Variant equivalent of that code?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [recently documented](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/craft-commerce-variants) template variable:

```
craft.commerce.variants.id(yourVariantId).first()
```

If you want to get a variant's product from the variant ID, you can use:

```
craft.commerce.products.hasVariant({id: yourVariantId}).first()
```

https://craftcommerce.com/docs/craft-commerce-products#hasvariant